# Get pwd/cwd with the $HOME variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, home

If I type pwd, I get:

```
/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/r2g.example
```

what I am looking to do is automatically generate this instead:

```
$HOME/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/r2g.example
```

what might be a good way to do that with a short command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work unless any of the directory names in the path to your current working directory include a comma:

```
pwd | sed "s,$HOME,\$HOME,"
```

Comment: thanks, that only handles the very beginning of the string right? just in case $HOME appears later in the string?

Comment: As written, it will replace `/home/$(whoami)` no matter where it might appear in the path.  This can be altered by instead using `"s,^$HOME,\$HOME,"` to pin the potential match to the beginning of the line.

Comment: You could also consider using parameter substitution on the shell's `PWD` variable e.g. `echo "${PWD/#$HOME/\$HOME}"`